# how to visualize image in postman

Tags: testing, postman

i want to extract the image from my get request i see it but something is wrong

this is my script in postman tests

```
let getdata = pm.response.json();
console.log(getdata);
let template = `
<html>
<body>
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<h1>{{images}}</h1>
<img src='{{images}}'  alt = 'recipe image'></img>   
</body>
</html>
```

`
in order to know if i post an image or not i try to use tests from postman to visualise the image sended to the server

```
pm.visualizer.set(template, {response: pm.response.json()});
```

and this is my body of the response that i get it from postman

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "string",
"description": "string",
"preparationTime": 1,
"cookingTime": 8,
"type": "NOURRITURE",
"recipeSeparations": [
    "LUNCH",
    "BREAKFAST"
],
"toAvoid": "Salt",
"toRecommend": "water",
"nbrCalories": 0.0,
"images": "amNpLnBuZw==",
"speciality": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Tunisienne"
},
"ingredientQuantityObjects": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "quantity": "100",
        "ingredient": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "string",
            "type": "AUTRE",
            "nbrCalories100gr": 100.0
        },
        "unity": "ml"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "quantity": "100",
        "ingredient": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "string",
            "type": "AUTRE",
            "nbrCalories100gr": 100.0
        },
        "unity": "g"
    }
],
"steps": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "instruction": "string",
        "tip": "string"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "instruction": "string",
        "tip": "stng"
    }
]
```

}

i want to display the full image but it goes like this [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
first of all you need to decode the image to the base64 and put the type of your image in the diament
see the snippet below

```
const base64ImgData = `data:photos/png;base64, 
 put your image code here`
const template = `
<img src="{{photo}}"> // here extract the data from the request
`
pm.visualizer.set(template, {photo: base64ImgData})
```

i hope that this is helpfull for everyone

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the response variables without writing the 'response' variable.
Replace **images** with **response.images**  Try something like that in your template:

```
let template = `
 <html>
  <body>
   <h1>{{response.name}}</h1>
   <h1>{{response.images}}</h1>
   <img src='{{response.images}}'  alt = 'recipe image'></img>
  </body>
 </html>
`
```